# How can I tell a QTableWidget to end editing a cell?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I'm showing a popup menu to select some values in a QTableWidget. The lowest item is a "Modify list" entry, when I select it a new window should automatically appear and the QComboBox should vanish and the cell return to a Qt::DisplayRole state.

Now Qt has all those nice API-calls like `QTableWidget.edit()` and `QTableWidget.editItem()`, what I'm really looking for is a `QTableWidget.endEditing()`, preferably without specifying the index of the cell, though I could get that using this call:

```
table.currentIndex()
```

… but I don't know if I can guarantee that the current cell is the cell being edited at all times.

Is there an API to close those kind of editors?

[image: Popup menu]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[QTableWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html) inherits 19 public slots from QWidget. One of those is setDisabled(), which should disable input events for that widget and all of its children.

I would try:

```
table.setDisabled( true );
table.setDisabled( false );
```

Although you said it does not work for you, there is an alternative method:
If you don't like that (the table loses focus, I believe), you can try using [EditTriggers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum). For example:

```
table.setEditTriggers( QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers );
```

Comment: Your first one did work, second one not. It doesn't matter that it loses focus because I show a modal dialog. I'll mark this answer as correct if nobody is going to propose a more natural solution.

Comment: I just fired up an example to test out EditTriggers and it appears to work (C++, Qt 4.4.3). I can click on each cell and such but I cannot double click on them to edit or anything at all. I don't know why it doesn't work for you. *shrug*

Comment: It's about closing the editor, not being not able to edit it. The next time one double clicks it should open the editor again.

Answer (score 7):

`table.setCurrentItem(None)` is what worked for me. (Don’t forget to block signals if you use some cellChanged/itemChanged slot function.)

This is with PyQt. For C++ I think replace None with NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use QTableWidget.closePersistentEditor() to close the editor. However, QAbstractItemView.closeEditor() may be closer to what you want, especially since you seem to be comfortable with the QModelIndex-based API and are already using a custom editor widget.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, none of the options worked properly. So, I figured: I need to send the key press event to the line edit itself. The following works with `QTreeView` but probably does work with any other view or widget that opens a line edit to edit cells.

```
QWidget* editingWidget = treeView->findChild<QLineEdit*>();
if(editingWidget)
{
    QKeyEvent keyPressEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Return, Qt::NoModifier);
    QApplication::sendEvent(editingWidget, &keyPressEvent);
    QApplication::processEvents(); // see note below
}
```

In my case, I wanted to start editing another field directly when having finished editing one item. That is why I put `processEvents` there, in most cases you can probably remove that line.

PS: yeah, it's C++, but should be easily adaptable to Python. I found this thread when I searched for the C++ solution, so maybe it helps anyone else, too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for list widgets. But, I got here trying to do something similar.

I was double-clicking a cell, and based on the column, bringing up a sub-form with a list, then when that was closed move to the next appropriate column based on the value selected.

My problem was I could get the value in the cell and "select" the next appropriate cell, but the original cell stayed selected in edit mode!

It finally dawned on me that my double-click was selecting the cell, ie. editing.

A single-click selects the cell but doesn't open an edit mode.

Side note: Never could get that sub-form to act truly modal, so I created a loop in the calling form: while the sub form was visible, with the only code being app.processEvents()