# Release edit in QTableWidget Cell

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Basically I am trying to give the enter key the same functionality as the return key has when editing a cell in a qtablewidget. If editing a cell and enter is pressed I want it to jump out of editing that cell just like return does. It feels like I've literally tried everything. I've even tried passing a return press event to qcoreapplication. It seems like if your editing a cell and you press a key to trigger an action it wont happen. That seems to be what the problem is and I'm not sure how to get around that. I've been setting up all of my keyboard shortcuts for this program as actions because it seems easier to set up. Is there another way to do this that would allow the key event to happen when editing a cell?

Can anyone help out with this?

Thank you in advance.

Tried this. It didn't work for me. [How can I tell a QTableWidget to end editing a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518447/how-can-i-tell-a-qtablewidget-to-end-editing-a-cell)

Comment: I'm not sure to get what you mean, could you create a small example reproducing the problem ? main function + basic qtablewidget + few steps to reproduce please ?

Comment: I did it through QT creator so it would talk a little bit of picking apart to give you a function you could just copy paste and reproduce the issue with. 

Basically I have a mainwindow that has a qtablewidget in it. The table has rows and columns, etc. I have a nextCell Action I also created that is connected to the Enter key. This was all done in the form editor. I have this in the main function: connect(ui->nextCell, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(on_nextCell_triggered()));

That connects the key to the slot, but the slot will not run when you are editing a cell if you press enter.

Comment: So basically, on_nextCell_triggered() is triggered when you use it properly, but is not when you're editing a cell... Did you try to check and maybe cancel a possible editing in your on_nextCell_triggerd() before doing anything else ?

Comment: yeah that exactly what I tried to do was cancel the editing in on_nextCell_triggerd() before anything else happens but it doesn't even run on_nextCell_triggerd() when enter is hit so its kind of pointless

Comment: Did you have a look at : http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/eventsandfilters.html. Maybe by handling properly your keys hit during your edition, you can perform different kind of actions by passing through key filtering... I'm really not sure it could help you, but it's worth having a look...

Comment: Yeah I'll take a look at that I might just have to re-implement this differently.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I looked at events and filters and it basically fixed my problem I set it up like this:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
  if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Enter) {
    if (ui->tableWidget_2->hasFocus()){
      on_nextCell_Triggerd();
  }
  else {
    QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
  }
}
```

and when the enter key is triggered it will autopull you out of edit mode. No need to do anything else.